# The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy. Undefined method Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I am working through [part4 of Symfony2](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html#Doctrine%202%20Repositories), and while updating the controller and helper class code i got the following error message

```
Undefined method 'getLatestBlogs'. The method name must start with either
findBy or findOneBy!
```

before i had put some code in controller that i shifted to my helper class as taught by tutorial, which result in the above error message.

```
<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Repository/BlogRepository.php
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * BlogRepository
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
*/
class BlogRepository extends EntityRepository
{
 public function getLatestBlogs($limit = null)
 {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
               ->select('b')
               ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC');

    if (false === is_null($limit))
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
  } 
}
```

And here is my controller file index Action Code:-

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php
class PageController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();

    $blogs = $em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog')
                ->getLatestBlogs();

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'blogs' => $blogs
    ));
    }

    // ..
}
```

I am attaching few lines from  /Entity/Blog.php file. please see if they are correct as per your answer.

```
<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Blog
 {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  */
  protected $id;
  --
  --
 }
```

Where Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You also had a newline between the annotation and the blog class, it should be directly below.

Comment: Deleting the *.orm.xml files work for me.

Comment: Its actually because of the **Access modifiers** in Repository if it is a private function you should start with `findBy, findOneBy` but as a good practice you **should not** make Repository functions public. _and Im using Symfony 4.3_

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Make sure that you have modified your entity class:

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Blog
{
    // ..
}
```

**the annotation `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")` is required.**

And don't forget to regenerate entities:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Blogger
```

### UPDATE

Remove annotation `@ORM\Entity`. It overrides correct annotation `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")`

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I have updated the question where i added Entity/Blog.php code. but i am still getting the error

Comment: @Showket. Updated my answer. You have two `@ORM\Entity` annotations. The last one must be removed

Comment: @MolecularMan: This solution is not working for Symfony 2.1.4. BlogRepository file is not generating. Is it a [bug](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/124). Do you have any advice !

Comment: @gowri, it may be a bug. You can create repository file manualy if it's the only problem.

Answer (score 9):

In my case adding proper annotation was insufficient. 
Deleting Doctrine Cache by `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` also not worked.
I generate my entities from database by commands

> php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
>   php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
>   php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle

First command generate orm.xml file for each DB Table in my project.
After DELETING all orm.xml files Annotations started work properly.

Comment: Deleting the *.orm.xml files did the trick! This should be more known for people who generated their entities from an existing structure.

Comment: Deleting orm.xml all files did the job.

Answer (score 4):

If youre using yml as config files for your entities try adding this:

```
Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog:
    type: entity
    table: Blog
    repositoryClass: Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository
    ...
```

and then as mentioned above:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Blogger
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solution is to delete all the orm.xml files added by generated entities. If you move the folder or delete, your mapping with repository will be operationnal.

Comment: This worked for me. I had reverse engineered my entities from a MySQL database. Once I deleted the orm.xml files I was able to run the custom queries in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using PHP-FPM then this issue might persist even after all the above solutions you have tried then use `sudo service php5-fpm restart` which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository")
```

Try putting the repository class at the same directory next to the Entity class:

```
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\BlogRepository")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to restart my vm (Vagrant Box)

Comment: I very much doubt that this is a **answer** to the question. If at all, this should be a comment. And you got enough reputation to comment!

Comment: @GhostCat for me it helped, so why shouldn't this be an answer? There is some issue with doctrine cache or something and this fixed it. I wish I would know more about this, but this solved my problem and I was searching for hours...

Comment: @Heisoka can you describe the source of the cache problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3 you are probably missing the repository class in your `orm.xml` file.

```
repository-class="Bundle\Repository\MyRepository"
```

#### Example:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="Bundle\Entity\MyEntity"
            table="tablename"
            repository-class="Bundle\Repository\MyRepository">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was no method in that particular place.
After placing/creating the according method the error was gone.