# Unable to Use Repository Class in Symfony2 with MongoDB

Tags: jquery, mongodb, symfony

Hi i am getting this error while i am calling a custom function defined inside my repository class in Symfony

**Code In Repo Class**

```
class TaskRepository extends DocumentRepository
{

public function searchByFirstLetter($letter)
{

    $query = $this->getDocumentManager()            
    ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM WorkStackTaskBundle:Users u WHERE u.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', $letter.'%');
    try {
    return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ODM\NoResultException $e) {
    return null;
    }}
```

**Code In Controller**
    $getasllusers =          dm->getRepository('WorkStackTaskBundle:Users')->searchByFirstLetter($_GET['keyword']);

But i am getting following error.

Undefined method 'searchByFirstLetter'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! 
**strong text**
Please suggest what might be wrong.

Thanks Advance

Comment: check [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172586/the-method-name-must-start-with-either-findby-or-findoneby-undefined-method-sym), maybe you can find some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your custom repository class in two locations

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="Work\StackTaskBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class Users
```

And in

```
# src/Work/StackTaskBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
_repository:
    class: Work\StackTaskBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    factory_service: doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager
    factory_method:  getRepository
    arguments: ["Work\StackTaskBundle\Document\Users"]
```