# Undefined method 'getDoctrine'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am currently working with Symfony2 and I am getting this ERROR message:

Undefined method 'getDoctrine'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
500 Internal Server Error - BadMethodCallException

This is my Entity Class:

```
 <?php

namespace Gestionresiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ResiduoRepository")
*/

class BodegaContieneResiduo
{


    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */

    protected $idContiene;

.....

}
```

This is the Controller's page Action method:

```
 <?php

namespace Gestionresiduos\ResiduoBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function portadaAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $ofertas= $em->getRepository('ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo')->findResiduosAlmacenados();
        return $this->render('ResiduoBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is my EntityRepository:

```
    <?php
namespace Gestionresiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ResiduoRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findResiduosAlmacenados()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $consulta = $em->createQuery('SELECT r FROM ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo');
        return $consulta->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

I also tried all solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172586/the-method-name-must-start-with-either-findby-or-findoneby-undefined-method-sym) by ScoRpion and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873149/symfony2-undefined-method-the-method-name-must-start-with-either-findby-or-find) by K-Alex

So, Where is THE PROBLEM ???

Comment: Inside of the repository you should be able to access the entity manager like this `$this->_em`. So you could just use: `$this->_em->createQuery()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Repository class, instead of:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

You should use:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
```

Reference:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html

Comment: You should mention, this must be changed in the repository.

Comment: Aaaah! you are a life saver!

Comment: In my case I had missed the Repository reference in the yml file for the entity. As soon as I declared the repository there, it started working.

Comment: But for `$em = $this->getEntityManager();` Can we use bindValue method to add prameters.?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first: @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ResiduoRepository") should contain full namespace. e.g: MyCompany\Namespace\Repository

Second you have a typo or you are calling the wrong repository:

```
$ofertas= $em->getRepository('ResiduoBundle:BodegaContieneResiduo')->findResiduosAlmacenados()
```

You are calling BodegaContieneResiduo but you defined repository as ResiduoRepository, you don't call it's classname but repository name.

Comment: Oh, and you should follow Dric512 answer too ;)