# The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! error

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I have a table which has relationship with Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media (SonataMediaBundle Entity) as 'media'

Normally I can make the form for Media like this below,

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($myMedia)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('media') // make the selectbox
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->getForm();
```

However I want to restrict to some medias from all medias, then I made this.

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($myMedia)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('media','entity',array(
            'class' => "Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media",
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQuery('SELECT r FROM ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Media');
            }))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->getForm();
```

However it shows the error like this.

```
Undefined method 'createQuery'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

I have found some [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172586/the-method-name-must-start-with-either-findby-or-findoneby-undefined-method-sym) and understood it is related with Repository.
But I am not sure which Repository should I point. THere is no Repository class under
  `Sonata\MediaBundle\` either `Application\Sonata\MediaBundle`

```
namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity;    
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia as BaseMedia;

@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Where is my repository???")

class Media extends BaseMedia
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     */
    protected $id;
```

---

BTW, my first code shows only select box for pictures(medias)

It is not useful enough to select pictures,
Is there a more suitable way for selecting pictures?

Comment: Search in project folder with MediaRepository keyword. When you find it look namespace and type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error, the `createQuery` method does not exist.

If you take a look at the `EntityRepository` class you will see that the right method is `createQueryBuilder()`.

If you look at the content of the method you'll see that it returns a `QueryBuilder` instance with already the right `select from` statement since you are supposed to get the right repository for your media entity from the `Entity` form type since you pass the class of your entity in the `class` option.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have checked the Doctorine/ORM/EntityRepository class and understood what you meant. I am not sure yet how can I use createQuery() instead of createQueryBuilder() though, for now createQueryBuilder() fulfill my purpose.

Comment: CreateQuery is a method from the `EntityManager` class. The `EntityRepository` class has a `getEntityManager()` method but it is protected so you can't call it from outside

Answer (score -1):

You have defined $er as `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity:Media')` which is the EntityRepository. What you need rather is the EntityManager which is `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` and then use the select statement that you have in the piece of code. Hope it helps!

Comment: `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` can be called in a controller but this is a closure in a form type.He is receiving the entity repository as parameter of the closure as the callback from the `query_builder` option always does.